# How do I get send a dm to the user who reacted to a message [DISCORD.JS]

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I looked everywhere, but my question is never answered. Here is what I want to do, in simple terms.

When a user reacts to a message in the following code, it will dm them saying 'you reacted!'

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
// I tried: reaction.author.send, doesn't work.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The fist its great reaction collector after some trigger, and then handle emoji. But this work only for certain time.

```
message.channel.send('Your Text').then(msg=> {
msg.react(`◀️`)
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return [`◀️`].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000 });
collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
    reaction.users.last().send('Some')
    .catch(console.error)
});
})
```

If you need handle it all time in specific message, you can listen event `reaction_add`

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.id !== 'YOUR MESSAGE ID') return
    user.send('Some')
    .catch(console.error)
  });
```

Comment: This should work, but if a user removes their reaction and adds it again it will re-trigger the message being sent.  If you don't want that behavior, you should store the user id's of the users you have messaged already and compare it.

Comment: @Tarazed However, the Collector will still be active and using memory. OP should use `Collector.stop()` when it collects, or use `Message.awaitReactions()` instead of a Collector.

Comment: Collector will stop after time

Comment: @Cipher Still not the most ideal, especially when multiple are active across the bot (a memory leak warning will be received after 10 are simultaneously active if my memory serves me right).